# Finding the average of multiple columns in Sqlite3 Pythonand ordering in descending order

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to find the average of three columns and order them in descending order. I'm newer to SQL but I have looked into this exstensively but I am still unsure how to find the average of three columns. Below is the code.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("class1.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM class1 avg (score1+score2+score3) DESC")
print("Class 1:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

This is the error that is returned.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Adair,Rowan CA2\Task 3\Code\DisplayTablesAverage.py", line 4, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM class1 avg (score1+score2+score3) DESC")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE:The program is now able to return the average but it only returns the average. I need to return the two other columns (surname,firstname) aswell. Here is the table code.

```
import sqlite3
connection=sqlite3.connect('class1.db')
cursor=connection.cursor()
sql_command1 = """
CREATE TABLE class1 (
surname VARCHAR (20),
forename VARCHAR (20),
score1 INTEGER,
score2 INTEGER,
score3 INTEGER);"""
cursor.execute(sql_command1)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Consult the syntax diagram at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the average, you have to put that in the `SELECT` clause. Then use `ORDER BY` to order them by that as well.

```
SELECT surname, forename, AVG(score1+score2+score3) AS avg
FROM class1
GROUP BY surname, forename
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

Comment: This works for returning the average alone as a float but I do also want the other two colums (surname,firstname) to also be returned, you will see in the question I have also added the table code.